# Getting date from String in Presto SQL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, presto, amazon-athena

I'm trying to use the presto query

```
SELECT date_parse(new_date,'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') FROM datatable
```

where new_date is of the format

```
"2/19/2020 03:06:48 AM"
```

However, I get the error:

> INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "2/19/2020 03:06:48 AM" is malformed at " 03:06:48 AM"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try running this: `SELECT date_parse('2/19/2020 03:06:48 AM','%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') ` does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Your format is correct:

```
presto> SELECT date_parse('2/19/2020 03:06:48 AM', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p');
          _col0
-------------------------
 2020-02-19 03:06:48.000
(1 row)
```

(verified on Presto 339)

See also [`date_parse` documentation](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_parse).

I would assume this might be some problem we fixed in Presto already.
Which Presto version are you using?

Comment: This is for the Amazon Athena query engine which is based on Presto 0.172, I believe.

Comment: I confirmed this query works on 0.172. Could you try the literal argument instead of new_date data just in case?